# Kotlin Android Studio how to merge two uint8 to one uint16

Tags: kotlin, bit-shift, uint16

I am reading data from bluetooth gatt characteristic. First data is one byte and I am successfully reading it by code:

```
val strValue = characteristic.value[0].toUByte()
```

characteristic.value[1] contains most significant byte of uint16

characteristic.value[2] contains least significant byte of uint16

What I want to do is get uint16 and put it into strValue.

I've tried to use shl function but it brings me this error:
[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkWC7.png)

I also tried this:
[IMAGE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5txg.png)

How to proper do this in Kotlin? I am good in C but Kotlin is new for me.

Comment: Insert a `toInt()` call right before the `shl` call. Use `or` to combine the numbers. And a uint16 is a `UShort` in Kotlin. `val strValue = (characteristic.value[1].toInt().shl(8) or characteristic.value[2].toInt()).toUShort()`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It almost works. There is one problem:
123
124
125
126
127
65408
65409
65410

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
val strValue :UShort = (characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,1) or characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,2).shl(8)).toUShort()
```